# independent dependent vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

i was given three vectors and I put them into matrix to check if they are independent or dependent
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&3\\
1&-1&1\\
1&2&4\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
i used row of reduction and i have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&3\\
1&-1&1\\
0&3&3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ row 3 divide by 3 then add row 2
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&3\\
0&-1&1\\
0&0&2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$row 3 divide by 2 then row 1 add row 2
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&4\\
0&-1&1\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ further reduction i get this eventually 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

my conclusion is it is independent but the answer from my lecturer is they are linearly dependent because $2x_1+x_2-x_3=0$

I was confused now. what is exactly mean by independent and dependent

Comment: You have made a mistake somewhere. I think the mistake is when you divide row $3$ by $3$ and add row $2$. Please check that step again.

Comment: thanks! now i have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&2\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
so how can we explain this is dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3. matrix is not correct.

Comment: thanks! now i have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&2\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
so how can we explain this is dependent?